# Set html elements value at "runtime"

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

In my html5 web application I am setting the value of some of the html elements when the DOM is loading. The values used are taken from some Javascript global variables, which are determined after the DOM loading is started but before the corresponding html DOM element is added. For now my code looks something like:

```
 myBtnText="some value";
 //....

 <input type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="DoSomeAction();" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("myBtn").value = myBtnText;
 </script>
```

The code is working, but I would like to improve it, in order to avoid the call made by document.getElementById("myBtn"), and also to make the code smaller. I'm thinking to simplify it do something like:

```
<input type="button" id="myBtn" value=/*<myBtnText>*/ onclick="DoSomeAction();" />
```

where // would be an expression which can help to obtain the value of the myBtnText global variable.

Any thoughts if this would be possible, and how can this be made?

Answer (score 1):

If you used JQuery you could do avoid the call to document.getElementById by doing something along the lines of:

```
$('#myBtn').val();
```

to get the value of the field and:

```
$('#myBtn').val("something");
```

To set the value of it. You can learn more here:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: I'm using jQuery, and I know about this mode of setting the elements value, but it will still call the document.getElementById("myBtn") method (from the jQuery js)

Comment: Well, if you are concerned about lines of code from a maintainability perspective, then just use JQuery. If you are concerned about a page speed or content load time, then you are probably going to have to stick to using traditional methods or do something like the other answer that suggests document.write as a possibility. If you have already loaded JQuery onto your page for other things, I don't know why you wouldn't just use it's functionality to write the values. You will have to do this when the document has loaded but it should be fast enough for the user not to notice a difference.

Comment: Raul Marengo - jQuery is loaded in the page, but it's placed at the end of the page, from a page speed concern also.

Comment: I would suggest that, if you are loading a minified version of JQuery from external servers, say http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery, the effect on loading times should be minimal. I would have never thought this could be a concern but, if JQuery is a no-no and document.writing isn't either then you are really cutting down your options. I suggest you try the JQuery method and then use Chromes Dev Tools to check loading times and assess your situation.

Comment: neither using jQuery, neither use of document writing are a "no-no", but I wanted to see if there is any syntax to access variables directly in html. My experience in html, Javascript and jQuery is very limited, and now I am trying to discover the boundaries imposed by these in web application development. And from the answers which I received or didn't received I can conclude that this kind of syntax it doesn't exist

Comment: It does exist server-side (php, shtml, coldfusion, jsp, etc). You could always consider migrating to a dynamic server technology.

Answer (score 1):

Why set the button value before DOM is ready? This is one way to do it during parsing the page.

```
myBtnText="some value";
 //....
/* some HTML */

    <SCRIPT>
    document.write('<input type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="DoSomeAction();" value="'+myBtnText+'"/>');
    </SCRIPT>

/* more HTML */
```

Comment: Teemu - I think of this approach also, but I was hopping it exist a mode to obtain the value of the global variable and set the value of the element directly in html. I think your answer needs a small update: document.write('<input type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="DoSomeAction();" value="' + myBtnText + '"/>');

Comment: You right with the "update", sorry for bad code. But this is the only way to set attributes in JavaScript while page is parsed. I think PHP would offer more sophisticated solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, what? That looks like an awful syntax. Are you trying to reinvent perl inside HTML? You'll completely break any parser with that sort of thing!

Since the problem you are trying to solve appears to be the amount of code why don't you just focus on reducing the code to appropriate functions, like:

```
<script>
function setValue(id, value) {
   document.getElementById(id).value = value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: SpliFF -one problem is the amount of code, another is that I need to access the DOM in order to retrieve the element although I know were it is, and that would be an "expensive operation" from what I had seen until know (I don't have very much experience in web site development). I though if there exist a possibility to set the element value directly from html it would be an improvement from performance perspective also.